# Homotopically equivalent compact Lie groups are diffeomorphic

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, lie-groups

I have the following conjecture:
Two homotopically equivalent compact Lie groups will be diffeomorphic. It may be necessary to restrict ourselves to only semisimple Lie groups. For simply connected compact Lie groups, such an assertion was known to Toda (1976), he even proved that they will be isomorphic.
Any commentary (for or against)?

Comment: Boekholt in [Compact Lie groups with isomorphic homotopy groups. J. Lie Theory 8 (1998), no. 1, 183–185] shows that compact connected Lie groups with isomorphic homotopy groups are locally isomorphic. The paper contains examples of homeomorphic semisimple groups that aren't isomorphic. This does not completely answer the question as far as I can see. From my location the paper can be easily found online via google search.

Comment: Scheerer, Hans. Homotopieäquivalente kompakte Liesche Gruppen. (German)
Topology 7 (1968), 227–232. "It is known that two compact connected Lie groups $G$ and $G'$ of the same homotopy type are isomorphic provided they are also simple. In general they need not be isomorphic. In this note the author proves that $G$ and $G'$ are always locally isomorphic, however." DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(68)90003-7

Comment: But the typical examples are indeed diffeomorphic. For instance, $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ is a semidirect product $\mathrm{SU}(2)\rtimes\mathrm{SO}(3)$, hence is (analytically) diffeomorphic to the direct product $\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{SO}(3)$, but they're not isomorphic.

Comment: I know all these articles. But none of them are about my hypotesis! I put it forward after reading these and some other articles.

Comment: It is the general case that interests me (when compact Lie groups are not necessarily simple and not necessarily simply connected)

Comment: Anyway this context is useful for the readers of your question.

Comment: @YCor: How do you you construct an isomorphism between ${\rm SO}(4)$ and ${\rm SU}(2)\rtimes{\rm SO}(3)$? How does ${\rm SO}(3)$ act on ${\rm SU}(2)$?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi the action is induced by conjugation. When viewing $SO(4)$ as $SU(2)^2$ modulo diagonal $C_2$, the copy of $SO(3)$ is the diagonal, and the normal $SU(2)$ is one factor.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi The diffeomorphism of $SO(4)$ and  $SU(2) \times SO (3)$ is a special case of one more general, but very simple, construction indicated in Toda's article (A note on compact semisimple groups (Japan. J.Math. 1976, V.2, N2). I recently  submitted an article with some generalization of this construction.

Comment: I  want to clarify some details of my hypothesis. It seems to me quite difficult to prove or disprove. There are very powerful topological techniques to be used here. Cohomology alone, even together with the Steenrod algebra, is not enough here. 
To refute my hypothesis, you need to use some more powerful topological invariants that are not homotopy invariants. And it seems to me even more difficult to prove it. Therefore, my question was directed not so much to specialists in Lie groups as to topologists who are proficient in the powerful modern technique of topological invariants.

Comment: Just to make sure: the question (modulo known things) is basically "given a connected, simply connected compact Lie group and two isomorphic central subgroups Z and Z' what keeps G/Z and G/Z' from being homotopy equivalent", yes?

Comment: @StefanWitzel Not quite.  The groups you describe will be homotopic, and generally not isomorphic as Lie groups (although they are under some conditions).   What is not known is whether they will be diffeomorphic as manifolds in general (although under some conditions one can show they will be).

Comment: @SeanLawton Now I'm confused. Whether or not the groups are isomorphic as Lie groups isn't mentioned in the question, just being homotopy equivalent and being diffeomorphic. From the comment by the OP and also from yours I gather that diffeomorphism is the one that is "understood" and homotopy equivalence is the one that is not, which is what I tried to say. Also, the problem being known for simply connected groups, it should boil down to coverings. So what did I get wrong? Perhaps you are saying, the groups should be G/Z and G'/Z' where G and G' may be diffeomorphic but not isomorphic?

Comment: @StefanWitzel I sent you an email trying to help you understand.

Comment: @StefanWitzel Please reread my conjecture: "If two equivalent compact Lie groups are homotopically equivalent, then they will be diffeomorphic (or, which is, I hope, equivalent here,  they will be homeomorphic). Not "simply connected". Not "isomorphic"!

Comment: SeanLawton clarified the question for me in a private message of which I would like to share one point, in case someone else wonders what there could be open on the topological side of the question: "Thus, the only remaining issue is to determine when and if G/Z_1 and G/Z_2 are diffeomorphic.  That is exactly what is not generally understood."

Comment: @StefanWitzel There are no words about  "G/Z_1 and G/Z_2" for some G.

Comment: @VictorGorbatsevich I have nothing to contribute toward answering your question. After having understood what the question is about I just tried to help others to reach the same point.

Answer (score 6):

The OP seems to be interested in evidence "for or against", so I will give a partial result.

*Definition*: Let $G$ be a compact connected semisimple Lie group, $\varphi_G:\tilde{G}\to G$ its universal cover, and $\Delta\cong \pi_1(G)$ the Deck group of $\varphi_G$.  There exists simple simply-connected compact groups $G_1,...,G_n$ so $\tilde{G}\cong \prod_{i=1}^nG_i$.  If $\Delta=\prod_{i=1}^n\Delta_i\leq \prod_{i=1}^nZ(G_i)\cong Z(\tilde{G}),$ we will say that $G$ is *adjoint-like*.

*Remark*: If $G$ is adjoint-like then it is necessarily a cartesian product of simple groups.  At one extreme, when $\Delta$ is trivial, it includes the simply-connected case, and at the other extreme when $\Delta$ is the full center, then $G$ is of adjoint-type (centerless); which motivates the name.

*Notation*: For a Lie group $G$ we will use the notation $G_0$ for its identity component, $DG:=[G,G]$ for its derived subgroup, and $Z(G)$ for its center.

*Theorem*: Let $G$ and $H$ be homotopic compact Lie groups. If both $DG_0$ and $DH_0$ are adjoint-like, then $G$ and $H$ are diffeomorphic.

*Proof*: First note that both $G$ and $H$ have a finite number of connected components.  Since $G/G_0\cong \pi_0(G)\cong\pi_0(H)\cong H/H_0$ they have the same number of components.  And since each component of $G$ (resp. $H$) is diffeomorphic to $G_0$ (resp. $H_0$), it follows that $G$ and $H$ are diffeomorphic iff $G_0$ and $H_0$ are diffeomorphic.

Second, by a result of Borel (Proposition 3.1 in *Sous-Groupes Commutatifs et Torsion des Groupes de Lie Compacts Connexes*, 1960), $G_0$ is diffeomorphic to $DG_0\times Z(G_0)_0$ and likewise $H_0$ is diffeomorphic to $DH_0\times Z(H_0)_0$.  In each case the identity component of the center is a torus (a product of circles).  Since $G$ and $H$ are homotopic their identity components are as well, and in particular, the fundamental groups are isomorphic.  Consequently, since the fundamental group of a semisimple Lie group is finite, the ranks of the central tori $Z(G_0)_0$ and $Z(H_0)_0$ can be determined from the corresponding fundamental groups.  Thus, $G_0$ and $H_0$ are diffeomorphic iff $DG_0$ is diffeomorphic to $DH_0$.

Lastly,since $G_0$ and $H_0$ are homotopic, and the central tori $Z(G_0)_0$ and $Z(H_0)_0$ are diffeomorphic (from the previous step), we conclude that $DH_0$ and $DG_0$ are homotopic as well.  From Theorem 2 in *Compact Lie Groups with isomorphic Homotopy Groups* (1998) by Boekholt, we have that $DH_0$ and $DG_0$ are locally isomorphic and hence their universal covering spaces $\tilde{DH_0}$ and $\tilde{DG_0}$ are diffeomorphic and their deck groups are abstractly isomorphic.  However, since $DH_0$ and $DG_0$ are both adjoint-like, they are cartesian products of simple groups, arising from the quotient of corresponding simple factors in $\tilde{DH_0}$ and $\tilde{DG_0}$ by central subgroups of those simple factors.  We conclude that each pair of corresponding simple factors are homotopic and hence by Theorem 9.3 in *The Cohomology of Quotients of Classical Groups* by Baum & Browder (1963) each pair of corresponding simple factors are diffeomorphic.

The result follows. $\Box$

*Corollary*:  If $G$ and $H$ are homotopic semisimple compact Lie groups that are simply-connected or adjoint-type, then they are diffeomorphic.

*Remark*: There is some tautological reasoning with this corollary since the simply-connected case is Toda's 1976 theorem in *A note on compact semi-simple Lie groups*, and I think it was used in one of the references I quote above (but there is nothing inconsistent).  But as far as I know the adjoint-type case seems new (although not by much).  Also, I am being slightly sloppy with the difference between "homeomorphism" and "diffeomorphism" since they are equivalent here, and similarly I am being sloppy with the difference between "weak homotopy equivalence" and "homotopic" since compact Lie groups are homotopic to CW complexes and Whitehead's theorm.

*Remark*: The analysis shows exactly how a counter-example to the general question could arise, if it exists.  One needs to look at simply-connected semisimple groups with at least two factors and quotient by isomorphic central subgroups that do not (both) arise as a product of the centers of the simple factors.  Any two groups constructed this way will be homotopic, and conversely the above proof shows that any two such groups that are homotopic must arise this way if they have any chance of not being diffeomorphic.

Comment: $\Delta$ is just $\pi_1(G)$, right?

Comment: Yes, the deck group of the universal cover is isomorphic to the fundamental group.  I added that notation.